# Cannot remove whitespace in string in r

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to remove whitespace from a column in a data frame in R.  I have a data frame that looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("fred dog", "joe cat", "lucy horse"), col2 = c("dog", "cat", "horse"))

        col1  col2
1   fred dog   dog
2    joe cat   cat
3 lucy horse horse
```

I have tried the following syntax with gsub:

```
gsub(" ", "", df$col1)

gsub("\\s", "", df$col1)

gsub("[[:space:]]", "", df$col1)

gsub("[[:blank:]]", "", df$col1)

gsub("\\t", "", df$col1)

gsub("\\n", "", df$col1)

gsub("\\r", "", df$col1)
```

Nothing seems to be working.  The output looks exactly like the input.  Can anyone give me some other ideas to try.  It doesn't seem to be whitespace but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: I get `gsub(" ", "", df$col1)
#[1] "freddog"   "joecat"    "lucyhorse"`  The output is not looking like the input

Comment: Can you show the output that you get?

Comment: Should work. Are you forgetting to assign the output to something you can refer to? `df$col1 <- gsub(" ", "", df$col1)`

Comment: The example that I used for the df is hypothetical.  I simplified it to ask the question but I know that it will work as written.  The data frame I have is more complex.  Specifically, if you have tried all of the conventional ways to replace whitespace and nothing works, what are the next steps?

Comment: why not dput some of your actual problematic data?

Comment: It would have been better (to save everybody's time) if you indicated in the post that the example works as intended or so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use `gsub`. Use the following `stringr` package instead:

```
library(stringr)

R: df$col1 <- str_replace_all(df$col1, fixed(" "), "")

       col1  col2
1   freddog   dog
2    joecat   cat
3 lucyhorse horse
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more about that "*Do not use gsub. Use the following stringr package instead:*" statement?

Comment: Thank you!  It worked- Any idea why stringr works better than gsub in this case?  I read the documentation but didn't see anything.

Comment: `gsub` **does** work as well (at least it does on my computer); `stringr` has a few similar (more readable) functions allowing to trim and replace when not dealing with particularly complicated regular expressions. Other than that both ways work equally good.